# Facebook Analytics - Breakdown table "Value" column

Tags: analytics, facebook

I have a simple question - in the below picture, what does the "Value" column mean? I can't find any documentation on it, and I don't know enough about the metrics to derive it from context here. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How does this relate to a website you control?

Comment: So this is facebook analytics, I am using what is called a "pixel" (facebook tech) its like google analytics, but it locks on to the traffic that is driven by my facebook ads and optimizes my ad delivery